# How are audio frames decoded by libavcodec?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav, libavformat

Here is how my process of decoding an audio stream  using ffmpeg's libav*

> [videofile]--> (read audio packets) --> [pkts queue] --> (decoder) -->
>   speaker's sample buffer

for some reason i need to insert a buffer after decoder

> [videofile]--> (read audio packets) --> [pkts queue] --> (decoder) -->
>   [samples buffer] --> speaker's sample buffer

Audio samples in the `samples buffer` are LPCM 16bits. To save the pts of the audio `sample buffer` i save pts of first samples. By that way, i can calculate pts of any sample in the buffer.

Problem is that the calculation is correct only if the audio stream contains contiguous audio samples. Do ffmpeg's decoded audio frames always contain contiguous samples?

Answer (score 1):

And why would that not be the case? A decoder will give out data in the order that it is to be presented to the upper layers.

Comment: let say decoder decodes an audio frame that contain samples from second 1->10, and next frame contains samples from second 15->20. If i push all those samples in the buffer, the buffer will be like [1..10 15..20]. Because i save only the pts of first sample, the calculation for samples from 15 to 20 will be wrong be cause there is silence part from second 11 to 14. Hope that make sense!.

Comment: the next frame will contain samples from 15->20 if the 11 to 14 are lost, right? Else it should come out in order, right? So if there is a gap in incoming samples, yes output will also have a gap and there is nothing the decoder can do. But if the bitstream coming in is complete and has valid syntax and semantics then you should get continous output.

Comment: is there possibly the case that there is no sample from 11 to 14 (slient part), the frame is not lost, there's just no audio sample for that duration?

Comment: @jAckOdE, why would such a case exist? If there is silence, encoders insert silence packets.

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg's decoded audio frames may contain samples in planar or nonplanar format.
you can check this using the

```
av_sample_fmt_is_planar(frame->format)
```

check the [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/samplefmt_8c.html)
you should make sure that you are passing the samples in correct format to the speaker.

If not then you can do sample format conversion using libswresample.

How does AVFrame contain planar and nonplanar data is explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888986/what-is-the-difference-between-av-sample-fmt-s16p-and-av-sample-fmt-s16)