# What is the difference between AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P and AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, transcoding, libav

What happens when you do a conversion from AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P to AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16?
How is the AVFrame structure going to contain the planar and non-planar data?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P` is planar signed 16 bit audio, i.e. 2 bytes for each sample which is same for `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16`.

The only difference is in `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16` samples of each channel are interleaved i.e. if you have two channel audio then the samples buffer will look like

> c1 c2 c1 c2 c1 c2 c1 c2...

where `c1` is a sample for channel1 and `c2` is sample for channel2.

while for one frame of planar audio you will have something like

> c1 c1 c1 c1 .... c2 c2 c2 c2 ..

---

**now how is it stored in AVFrame:**

- for planar audio:

data[i] will contain the data of channel i (assuming channel 0 is first channel).

however if you have more channels than 8, then data for rest of the channels can be found in extended_data attribute of AVFrame.

- for non-planar audio

data[0] will contain the data for all channels in an interleaved manner.

Comment: if the audio data is stored in data[0] for non-planar formats, does that mean we have to read that array index 16/24 bits at a time, until NULL?

Like, each sample doesn't get it's own array index, each index is associated with a channel, instead? so it's just a single long list o samples...

Comment: I assume `c1 c1 c2 c2` must refer to the bytes in the buffer, not the samples. Should either change it to `c1 c2 c1 c2` for samples, or update the text to say bytes.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have been struggling several days with FFmpegs audio data and CMSampleBuffer creation via CMBlockBufferCreation. Your answer was the breakthrough I needed. Would it be possible to upvote the answer more than once, I would upvote it to Inf+.

Answer (score 0):

- In `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P` the data come in decoded_frame->extended_data while in AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16 the data come in decoded_frame->data
- In `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P`  the data is planar
- In `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16`  the data is interleaved, I suppose you know what is means.

Sample code is available in Sourceforge Libav based software